# Unable to save the current state of moniter of jwPlayer in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, jwplayer

Here is my 'moniter' viewmodel

```
var Data=function(){
            var self=this;
            var moniter;
            self.applyMoniter=function(mon){
                self.moniter=mon;
            }
```

And here is the function by which I am trying to have local storage in HTML5.

```
        var loadData=function(field){               
            return ko.toJS(localStorage.getItem(field));                
        }

        var saveData=function(field, value){
            localStorage.setItem(ko.toJSON(value), storedComment);
        }

        var moniter = options.components.screen.ctrl.moniter;
        var data=loadData() || new Data();
        data.applyMoniter(moniter);
```

But can't access the moniter object. Any ideas to make it working as local storage?

When I use the function for moniter

```
moniter.onPlay(function(event){
                //log(1,"Sync: onPlay event=",event);
                self.currentState(event.newstate);
```

I get the error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'onPlay' of undefined`

Comment: Do you have a link to where this is running?

Comment: Actually it is running on my local machine. You can see the edited question.

Comment: Sorry, I can't debug properly without a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, done.
I stated with a fresh local storage with mapping in knockout.js.